# Form_tag url_for_options nil action to the controller itself

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

My case is that i have more controllers with sharing one view and i'm trying to change dinamycally the action on a form passing a variable defined in the controller

Trying some solution i've observed that if i have a nil variable in url_for_options form_tab variable, the form in the view has the right controller path from where the view was called

`<%= form_tag nil, :method => :get, :class => 'search' do %>`

is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: If the :url option is not specified, by default the form will be sent back to the current url

Comment: It seems as default behavior for form. The Design feature )

Answer (score 8):

Note that if you pass an empty string, instead of nil, you get a slightly different behavior:

```
form_tag nil
```

creates

```
<form action="(URL based on current controller and action)">....
```

While

```
form_tag ""
```

creates

```
<form action>....
```

If the URL of the page you're on is, say, "/foo/bar" (for FooController#bar), then the two are functionally equivalent.
If the URL of the current page is "/foo/bar?a=1&b=2", the former will continue to point at just "/foo/bar", while the latter will result in a form that submits to the full URL (querystring included). This is because the HTML standard (no action or empty action = use current URL, including querystring) is used by the latter. Instead the former triggers a Rails standard (nil for url_for => use current controller and method).

Just thought it's worth mentioning as there are cases where the HTML standard for an action-less form is more useful (ie. where you want querystring parameters to be sticky), and the subtle difference in behavior between nil and "" is easy to miss.

Comment: oops, sorry, just noticed @luca-milan already covered this below

Answer (score 2):

The solution is using an empty action attribute on a form to submit that form to the current page. and is described on [RFC 2396](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt)

> 4.2. Same-document References
>
> A URI reference that does not contain a URI is a reference to the
>   current document.  In other words, an empty URI reference within a
>   document is interpreted as a reference to the start of that document, 
>   and a reference containing only a fragment identifier is a reference
>   to the identified fragment of that document.  Traversal of such a
>   reference should not result in an additional retrieval action.
>   However, if the URI reference occurs in a context that is always
>   intended to result in a new request, as in the case of HTML's FORM
>   element, then an empty URI reference represents the base URI of the
>   current document and should be replaced by that URI when transformed
>   into a request.

A strange behaviour when

url_for_options == nil

`<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/welcome" class="search" method="get">`

url_for_options == ""

`<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action class="search" method="get">`

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug. If you don't provide any action to 'form_tag' or 'form_for', By default it will be posted to same controller where view is called from.